# Getting numpy error when using azureml-sdk

Tags: python, azure, numpy

hy I followed the installation instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-configure-environment)

and installed with

```
pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk[notebooks,automl] azureml-dataprep --ignore-installed PyYAML
```

It seem to work but a simple

```
import azureml.core
azureml.core.VERSION
```

Throws me a numpy error

```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-3-08b704cd5542> in <module>
> ----> 1 import azureml.core
>       2 azureml.core.VERSION

    c:\users\werth\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\azuresdk\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\__init__.py in <module>
          4 
          5 """Setup file for core package."""
    ----> 6 from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
          7 from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment
          8 from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration

    ... I did not include the total traceback as it is apparently a Azure import problem.

    AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

It seems that the workspace has a problem. But I cannot think why. The Notebook is in a subfolder of the working directory. Numpy is installed.

If you would have an idea I would be thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

Hi greatest Floridaman,

the answer is simple. During the installation of the azureml-train-automl 1.0.8 package, the numpy package needs to be maximum at version 1.15.0

So just downgrade numpy to that version

```
conda install numpy=1.15.0
```